# Does Xdebug depend on PHP version (VSCode IDE)?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, windows-10, wamp, xdebug

I am struggling to enable debugging in VSCode. I was following a few different tutorials but none of them worked for me. What I don't understand is if I have multiple php versions installed, the newest one, but also some older and currently, I am working on a project that uses and older version of php (`php5.6.40`) do I need to configure Xdebug to work with the newest version of php I have installed, and that way it will also support older versions, or do I need to enable it for each specific version of php to make it work for this project I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each `xdebug.so` (or `php_xdebug.dll`) file only works with the PHP version it has been compiled for. So for example if you have an Xdebug compiled for PHP 7.3.5, then it will not work for PHP 7.2.11, but it will work for PHP 7.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you must find each xdebug.so file and get its path, as example:

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
```

Then you must configure each php version xdebug.ini file. Example for PHP 7.0:

Edit

```
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

And configure this way:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_error_trace=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
```

Then must restart apache
sudo service apache2 restart

On Windows will change directories but must be the same working way.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it is Windows 10 OS I am using. But still, it shouldn't differ much. Even after configuring `.ini` file, I still don't even get option to choose to debug PHP in VSCode, only Node.js (which was tehre by default).

Comment: Have you installed PHP Debug extension on VSCode ?